# How to set the first selector value to 1 in Cake PHP Form->select

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.0

I am a new user to Cake PHP and I am going through the cake book of Cake PHP. When I am using the $this-Form->select('field', $array); the first value is always set to 0. I want this that the first selector has a value of 0.

```
$this->Form->select(
    'field',
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
);
Output:

<select name="field">
    <option value="0">1</option>
    <option value="1">2</option>
    <option value="2">3</option>
    <option value="3">4</option>
    <option value="4">5</option>
</select>
```

Can anyone help me with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how arrays are created by default, if you don't supply keys. To use the same values for keys and values, try this:

```
$values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
$this->Form->select(
    'field',
    array_combine($values, $values)
);
```

Comment: This does not work exactly how you told me, However, I used the array_combine to combine the ID with the names and it works :). 

`$combine = array_combile($id, $name);`

$this->Form->select("name_field, $combine");`

Thanks

Comment: If you provide the actual data that you want, there might be an easier solution.

Comment: Not a problem. You helped me a lot anyway :). Thanks